How to write 'medicalSpeciality' schema - is my code correct?
I have a webpage that is about Medical Specialty (heart disease) and it's a landing page. I was wondering how to write a medicalSpeciality schema for the above webpage?
Could someone please help me with an example? Is the code below correct?
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "MedicalSpecialty",
  "name": "Cardiology",
  "alternateName": "Heart Specialist",
  "description": "A branch of medicine that deals with the diseases and disorders of the heart.",
  "healthCondition": {
    "@type": "MedicalCondition",
    "name": "Heart Disease",
    "alternateName": "Cardiovascular Disease",
    "description": "A class of diseases that involve the heart or blood vessels."
  },
  "guideline": {
    "@type": "MedicalGuideline",
    "name": "Guidelines for the management of heart failure",
    "description": "These guidelines aim to improve the diagnosis and treatment of heart failure.",
    "guidelineDate": "2020-01-01",
    "evidenceLevel": "High",
    "evidenceOrigin": "Clinical Experience",
    "guidelineSubject": {
      "@type": "MedicalEntity",
      "name": "Heart Failure"
    }
  },
  "relevantSpecialty": {
    "@type": "MedicalSpecialty",
    "name": "Internal Medicine"
  },
  "study": {
    "@type": "MedicalStudy",
    "name": "The impact of lifestyle changes on heart disease",
    "description": "A study to investigate the impact of lifestyle changes on the progression of heart disease.",
    "status": "Completed",
    "datePublished": "2019-01-01",
    "outcome": "Significant reduction in the progression of heart disease with lifestyle changes."
  }
}
</script>


Multiple questions are not a good fit for the format of this site - please ask just one per post.

Who is using this data?  Do they say they can read it?  Does it have everything in it they need?
